# this.$router.push() is not recognizing inside google map place_changed function

Tags: google-maps, laravel-5, vuejs2

I have a textbox which is connected to google map place autocomplete function . I called the new `google.maps.places.Autocomplete()` inside vue mounted property . Based on the search results i want to redirect my page to a search filter page calling this.$router.push() function . But I don't know why `this.$router.push()` is not recognizing inside google map `place_changed()`.

I called `this.$router.push()` inside `mounted(){}`. Its working fine but I need to recognize `this.$router.push()` inside `place_changed()`.

```
<input id="modal-filters-Main"
                                        placeholder="Enter an address, neighborhood, city or ZIP code"
                                        class="typeahead form-control form-ready-for-bubble" >
```

```
var SearchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('modal-filters-Main'));
            SearchBox.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                 this.place = SearchBox.getPlace();
                 this.formatter = this.place.formatted_address;
                 this.lower = this.formatter.toLowerCase();
                 this.modified = this.lower.replace(", ","_");
                this.$router.push('/listing/'+this.modified);
                // window.location.href = '/listing/'+modified;
            });
```

Comment: Change `function() { ... }` to `() => { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retain your code you can add this inside your function.

let $this = this

but it seems dirty and old, better change function to ()=>